# Range of the sum of two operators

Tags: operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $A$ is  closed densely defined operator on $X$ and $B$ is a bounded operator on $X$. Let $C$ the operator defined by $C=A+B$. 
 I would ask about,  $\mathcal{R}(C)$,  the range of $C$ .
Is it equal to  $\mathcal{R}(A)+\mathcal{R}(B)$ or $\mathcal{R}(A)\cap\mathcal{R}(B)$ ???

Comment: Have you thought about the finite dimensional case?

Answer (score 0):

Respect the parentheses- you need to form a new operator $C=A+B$ by $C(x)=A(x)+B(x)$ and ask about $\mathcal{R}(C)$